# Организация микросервиса Golang

Tags: golang, микросервисы, grpc

Простой пример,есть клиент, вызывающий какие-либо методы, на стороне сервера необходимо реализовать простой счетчик количества вызовов этих методов и,к примеру, передавать этот счетчик на другой клиент.Не могу понять сам принцип  реализации(передачи),пробовал через UnaryServerInterceptor, но ведь он имеет сигнатуру:

```
`func UnaryServerInterceptor(
    ctx context.Context,
    req interface{},
    info *grpc.UnaryServerInfo,
    handler grpc.UnaryHandler,
) (interface{}, error) {
    reply, err := handler(ctx, req)

    return reply, err
}`
```

то есть, отсюда не получится извлечь какие-то данные и дальше их передать.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как в микросервисной архитектуре,используя golang+gRPC,реализовать подобное?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Счетчик можно сделать через interceptor, в контекст вложить значение которое будет при каждом вызове увеличиваться и новый контекст вкладывать в handler, а уже в реализованном методе извлекать это значение.

Пример:

```
// CounterUnaryServerInterseptor interseptor, который будет производить подсчет вызовов методов сервера 
func CounterUnaryServerInterseptor() grpc.UnaryServerInterceptor {
    methods := make(map[string]int64, 0)
    return func(ctx context.Context, req interface{}, info *grpc.UnaryServerInfo, 
        handler grpc.UnaryHandler) (interface{}, error) {
        var count int64
        var ok bool
        if count, ok = methods[info.FullMethod]; ok {
            count += 1
        }
        methods[info.FullMethod] = count
        newCtx := context.WithValue(ctx, "count", count)
        return handler(newCtx, req)
    }
}

// MethodGRPCServer реализация метода в котором извлекается значение `count`
func (s *Server) MethodGRPCServer(ctx context.Context, req *pb.Request) (*pb.Response, error) {
    countInterface := ctx.Value("count")
    count, ok := countInterface.(int64)
    if !ok {
        log.Printf("Can't cast to int64, data: %+v", countInterface)
    }
    log.Print(count)

    // Ваш код

    return response, nil
}

func main() {
    // Инициализация gRPC сервера
    grpcServer := grpc.NewServer(
        CounterUnaryServerInterseptor(),
    )
    // Регистрация методов
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста,а как быть,если у меня server side streaming,и в сгенеренном proto файле у метода в сигнатуру не передается context?