# golang grpc передача контекста между сервисами в микросервисе

Tags: golang, микросервисы, grpc

Предположим есть код

```
   func methodCountInterceptor() grpc.UnaryServerInterceptor {
    var counter int
    return func(ctx context.Context, req interface{}, info *grpc.UnaryServerInfo, handler grpc.UnaryHandler,
    ) (some interface{}, err error) {
    count++
    return handler(ctx,req)
    }
 }

func adminInterceptor() grpc.StreamServerInterceptor {

    return func(srv interface{}, ss grpc.ServerStream, info *grpc.StreamServerInfo, handler grpc.StreamHandler) error {

        return handler(srv, ss)
    }
}
```

есть фрагмент proto файла:

```
 service Log {
    rpc Logging (Interval) returns (stream Event) {}

    }

service Some {
    rpc Something(Nothing) returns(Nothing) {}

}
```

как правильно значение переменной count из UnaryInterceptor передать в rpc Logging?

Comment: Подобный вопрос уже задавали, вы можете посмотреть здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/940811/%D0%9E%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0-golang/941797#941797

Comment: @ЕвгенийГаврилов не совсем то же самое,тут идут разные сервисы и тут поток идёт,а там передача значения внутри одного сервиса.

Comment: Тогда не совсем понятно, что именно вы хотите. В у вас на входе в grpc метод unary, соответственно туда можно пробросить данные в контекст.

Comment: это понятно,а как значения,полученные в unaryInterceptor(тот же счетчик например ) начать стримить в другой подключившийся клиент?например один клиент вызывает методы унарно,количество считается и передается потоком другому клиенту?